# Microsoft Cognitive Service - Recommendation API Limit exceeds

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using the User to Item recommendation and I am receiving the following error when using a value which is greater than 150:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "(EXT-0108) Passed argument is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "EXT-0100",
      "message": "The requested numberOfResults '500' exceeds the limit of '150'. Please choose smaller value."
    }
  }
}
```

This is obvious where by if I change the value to 150 or less, I get the recommendations. But my question is as follows:

1. Is there a way to increase the limit?
2. How can I tag all the other contents sent via the catalogue file if only 150 items max is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft Support and their response was that we **cannot** update the number of result.

For them, 150 recommendation items are large enough and even upgrading the different tier (package) will not allow the increase of the number of result to greater than 150.